# Nuxtjs - where is onMounted executed?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am considering Nuxtjs for a dashboard application, but I am stuck on a very basic case, and I can't find clear indications on the web.

I need some code to be executed client side when each instance of my component is ready,
I (try to) use the composition API.
After some failed attempts, I tried the following code (on a page component)

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
onMounted(() => {
    console.log("HELLO!!!")
})
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello Index</h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

But the **message doesn't get logged neither in the client console neither in the server console**....

??? Where does this code gets executed ???

And furthermore, how could i get the code to be executed on the client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was from a script in error in the "plugins" section of the nuxt.config.ts...

I though this error was totally unrelated, but it seems to have prevented the onMounted code to be executed, but did not break other parts of the page....

onMounted does get executed on client.